# Insert complex objects from C# into SQL Server without Entity Framework and data tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper, dapper-contrib

How to insert complex objects from C# into SQL Server without using Entity Framework and data tables (I thought about Dapper.Contrib but it is only for entities).

I'm using stored procedures and Dapper for now, but I can insert only one object and also - only with dynamic parameters so it not what I looking for.

For example:

```
DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("ID", user.UserInformation.ID);
p.Add("DELEGATORID", user.UserRole.DelegateID ?? string.Empty);
p.Add("APPROVER", user.UserRole.Approver);
p.Add("DELEGATOR", user.UserRole.IsDelegator);
p.Add("SEARCHTEXT", searchText);
```

and then insert. But I need to do 2 more inserts.

For example - I want to get 3 complex objects to insert in the stored procedure and then execute 3 stored procedure for each object

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd use an ORM that takes care of this but one option is to use raw SQL strings in that you build the entire query as a string (or in several strings), parameterize it and execute it. A quick google gives and example here; https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59863/transaction-handling-for-multiple-sql-statements. Important points of note are;

- Values are parameterized
- The statements execute as a transaction (and so will all get rolled back in event of an issue

Answer (score 0):

> > How to insert complex objects from C# into SQL Server without using Entity Framework and data tables

SQL Server can parse [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server), and newer versions can also parse [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server).  So the simplest way to insert shaped data into SQL Server without an ORM is to send an XML or JSON document and parse it on the server.